# Decrypt RSA with a private key that exists as a string in Python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

I tried to decrypt rsa using a private key that exists as a string, but it failed.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The private key is a string and exists as shown above.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

Pkey ="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"

s="AQEAN2+hgPwYzFATKPJfkXyTQKe9kvUTmT6LhASj2YI0T2KhBO7gSpKbNx/EXF4JYaWcwJVhJwiudgCFvoJMK9qJtnpLFmG12f8drygke+MPo5n2flHFPiKRmJCcCRM/VR8gL+xlbFIZNBL/o4onbqC1XfeQygiHe6tKXGiAZGXcJejbnob+/V+sL46x076KjurqLjcFMH+SCXomhuQZOiSqRqmeAsE6kL8wlj2yhTUfqAL/GuTTRziT6Syp0zJ7dprgCYOXBWbkLD9X6Vw39Db75kLd6Vx5zKT5jUQeU8eTN6pYfIiymlXwModf3TFBG1CObxzxzrevTXxFfIahFZGMAhDltmmcy7GUWDB7Qav24psONYaH+P69VfTimRzbrLMCfPb3zqp0cS8glMZ5YQuWqpigQRlQBhGq4rN9TGxBE3F1YRByBg+CHelBCHZj+2swHauVRmgy0CKU2/nmKpMrypKguFjjE6+bBur8b2AE28LSfjqxPZJx2BM="


code_bytes = s.encode('UTF-8')
by=base64.b64decode(code_bytes)

key = PKCS1_OAEP.new(Pkey)

rsadecrypt=key.decrypt(str(by))
```

Attempted to decode string 's' after base64 decoding.

However, an error was issued as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isin-yeong/Desktop/element/code/rsadecrypt.py", line 14, in <module>
    rsadecrypt=key.decrypt(str(by))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 161, in decrypt
    modBits = Crypto.Util.number.size(self._key.n)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

How do I convert 'Pkey' that exists as a string into a private key and decode 's' decoded with base64?
The following methods are used for decryption:

```
"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"
```

Comment: Apart from the incorrect key import, the wrong padding is used. The PyCryptodome counterpart to `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` is `PKCS1_v1_5` (and not `PKCS1_OAEP`). Second, the ciphertext is apparently corrupted: The posted (and thus compromised) private key has a length of 2048 bits = 256 bytes, i.e. the ciphertext must be of the same length. But the posted (Base64 decoded) ciphertext is 380 bytes long (`len(by)`). Furthermore, in `decrypt()` not `str(by)` but `by` must be passed.

Comment: You also have a typo in `Pkey`, the Base64 encoded body is `...boc61` and not `...boc6` (i.e. the last character is missing). If this is fixed, the key can be imported with `RSA.importKey(base64.b64decode(Pkey))` (or from a file, as described in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the private key you posted first in a file with the name 'pkey.pem', and instead of writing the string directly into your code, use the following to upload the key:

```
Pkey = RSA.importKey(open('pkey.pem').read())
```

For more information you can look [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/public_key/rsa.html), the documentation of pycryptodome.

---

**edited according to [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco)'s comments**

Your code should looks as follows:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

s="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"
  
code_bytes = s.encode('UTF-8')
by=base64.b64decode(code_bytes)

Pkey = RSA.importKey(open('pkey.pem').read())

key = PKCS1_v1_5.new(Pkey)

sentinel = get_random_bytes(16)

rsadecrypt=key.decrypt(by,sentinel)
```

Pay attention that you still going to get the following error:

> ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.

as Topaco explained in the comments

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I make a pem file?

Comment: Copy the text into a text editor (notepad for example), and 'save as' the file with the name 'pkey.pem'. Pay attention you don't save it as a text file (this will add a suffix of '.txt' to the file and won't work afterwards).

Comment: The suffix on the file is irrelevant and a suffix of `.txt` has no special significance and is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: If the suffix is different, changes are needed in the code above...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems already noted in the comments by [@Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco):

> Apart from the incorrect key import, the wrong padding is used. The
> PyCryptodome counterpart to RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding is PKCS1_v1_5 (and
> not PKCS1_OAEP). Second, the ciphertext is apparently corrupted: The
> posted (and thus compromised) private key has a length of 2048 bits =
> 256 bytes, i.e. the ciphertext must be of the same length. But the
> posted (Base64 decoded) ciphertext is 380 bytes long (len(by)).
> Furthermore, in decrypt() not str(by) but by must be passed.
>
> You also have a typo in Pkey, the Base64 encoded body is ...boc61 and
> not ...boc6 (i.e. the last character is missing). If this is fixed,
> the key can be imported with RSA.importKey(base64.b64decode(Pkey))

When those are addressed we see that `s`, after base64 decoding, is too long to be the result of RSA encryption with a 2048 bit modulus. However by trying all offsets into the base64-decoded `s` and taking the next 256 bytes we get a successful decrypt at offset 3.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/74840474/238704
import base64

from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes

private_key_pem = '''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'''

s = "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"

code_bytes = s.encode('UTF-8')
by = base64.b64decode(code_bytes)
private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key_pem)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
sentinel = get_random_bytes(16)
rsadecrypt = cipher.decrypt(by[3: 3 + 256], sentinel)
if rsadecrypt == sentinel:
    print('failure')
else:
    print(f'success: {rsadecrypt.hex(" ")}')
```

output is:

```
success: 48 90 c1 c5 ed fd 67 84 ad 82 df d1 5b 22 40 6f
```

I don't know what the rest of the bytes of `s` are all about.

[PKCS1 version 1.5 encryption padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2.1) is not all that great and is basically deprecated in favor of OAEP padding. One of the weaknesses is the unacceptably high probability that a decryption with the wrong key and/or corrupted ciphertext will succeed. It's unlikely in this case, but not unlikely enough to completely discard the possibility. Although you've provided no additional details about what the payload is supposed to be, the 16 random-looking bytes suggests a key of some sort, perhaps an AES-128 key.